# If or VLOOKUP in excel sheet

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup, vba

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZYaf.png)

See Here in Image 1, I want to sort all the male and Female in a different Sheet
Like if Column D read Male Than it Should automatically Show in another Sheet, Something like given in Image 2,

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sxlK.png)

What Formulla or tool I should use...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: VLOOKUP is the correct function, I recommend you read up on how to use it https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1

Comment: A PivotTable is way better than functions at this type of thing. I'll add this as an answer at the other thread, seeing that this one is locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using the `MATCH` and `OFFSET` functions

For convenience I defined a named range `GENDER` to cover the column of genders:

[image: Sheet of people]

On the men sheet I split up the `MATCH` and `OFFSET` functions for readability but these could be incorporated into a single function. I also omitted the logic to filter out the `#N/A` values, but again. This can be done with the `isna()` function.

[image: Sheet of men]

The relevant formulae are

```
A2: =MATCH("m",Workbook2!GENDERS,0)
A3: =MATCH("m",OFFSET(GENDER,A2,0),0) + A2
A4: =MATCH("m",OFFSET(GENDER,A3,0),0) + A3
...
...


B2: =OFFSET(people!A$1,$A2-1,0)
B3: =OFFSET(people!A$1,$A3-1,0)
...
...

C2: =OFFSET(people!B$1,$A2-1,0)
C3: =OFFSET(people!B$1,$A3-1,0)
...
...
```

[image: Formulae on sheet of men]

I hope this is enough to get you going

Comment: **Thanks a lot bro**, This was exactly what I want.....